# bash: ./mybashfile.sh: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I created a bash file `mybashfile.sh` containing below commands, but running it in the terminal giving me a `Permission Denied Error` I tried running the file from `su` but same `Permission Denied Error` for `su`.

I am running the command like this -

> $: ./mybashfile.sh

It is in a directory containing `mybashfile.sh`

My `mybashfile.sh` file -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
redis-server --save "" &
sleep 1
redis-cli flushall
cd ~/Documents/class-prj/class-prj
npm run app.js
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: su is substitute user...

Answer (score 1):

Set the mode to executable:

```
chmod +x mybashfile.sh
```

Comment: This must be a duplicate...

Comment: ahh thx  a lot its working ...wow